# Can't make the css to display html

Tags: html, css

I have a html page and css to apply to this html.

**HTML code**

```
<label>id</label>              <span>1</span>
<label>Name</label>            <span>My name is</span>
<label>Address</label>         <span>Address, Address 2, Address 3, UK</span>
```

**CSS code**

```
label{
    min-width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
span{
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

I want to display the HTML as this

```
Id:              1
Name:            My name is
Address:         Address, Address 2, Address 3, UK
```

but my code display this way.

```
Id:              1
Name:            My name 
is
Address:         Address, Address 2, 
Address 3, UK
```

How do I correct this.

Comment: For start, correct `<span>1</label`. Next, try to be more accurate what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: that CSS doesn't really look like it will do what you want anyway. have you considered using a table, and applying the field widths with CSS instead? that will at least contain any flow breaks to the column they should be in.

Comment: I agree with @FrankThomas a table is more appropriate for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding display:block; and white-space:nowrap; to the span css. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqa7G/)

However, I do think you should explore using a table. A table is good when you want to display data.

Comment: Is using tables is best way. i' design sit which is html validate

Comment: Is using tables is best way. i wont to design a site which is html validate

Comment: Tables *are* valid, including [in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#tabular-data). What doctype are you expecting to validate against? As Frank said, you should use tables for grid-data.

Comment: I will have lost of data e.g. i have search page which will have results over 100. so it good idea to use tables rather then div's. I was told in past to use div on website as search engine like this type of site.

Comment: Sorry this is my doctype. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="{lang mkey='ENCODING'}"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: @user264767 Don't use tables to design a site (or navigation) but use them to display grid data.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in Divs? I gave it a shot on cssdesk.com and it worked:

```
<div><label>id</label><span>1</span></div>
<div><label>Name</label><span>My name is</span></div>
<div><label>Address</label><span>Address, Address 2, Address 3, UK</span></div>
```